# Thinking in java constructor initialization

Tags: java

I have a question on page 128 of Bruce Eckel's Thinking In Java 4th Edition, the second paragraph, the last sentence it asks:

> what would happen if an overloaded constructor were defined that did not initialize `w3` and there wasn’t a “default” initialization for `w3` in its definition?

I found this statement is confusing to understand, could experts or readers of this book help me a little? Thanks!

Comment: Can you add sentences before or after that?? We need the context in which it was written..

Comment: Just a random guess: `w3` would be `null`?

Comment: Rohit is right. Do you expect that majority of people have exactly this edition of this book on their desktops at any time?

Comment: Since this question only makes sense to people who have that book, and is only interesting to people who were puzzled by that quoted sentence, I'm voting to close this as too localized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Window w3 = new Window(3);`

It is just guarding if someone does not initialize `w3` properly in the overloaded constructor. Such field instantiation is automatically put at the beginning of each constructor. So even the overloaded one will receive the `w3` initialization.

If you declare only `Window w3`, then `w3` will remain `null` when the overloaded constructor is executed.

Here is the code from the book:

```
import static net.mindview.util.Print.*;
    // When the constructor is called to create a
    // Window object, you’ll see a message:
    class Window {
        Window(int marker) 
        { 
            print("Window(" + marker + ")"); 
        } 
    }

   class House { 
       Window w1 = new Window(1); 
       // Before constructor 
       House() {
           // Show that we’re in the constructor:
           print("House()");
           w3 = new Window(33); // Reinitialize w3
       }
        Window w2 = new Window(2); 
        // After constructor void f() { print("f()"); } 
        Window w3 = new Window(3); 
    // At end 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Every field type in Java has a predefined defaault value, which is null, zero, or false, respectively as applicable to the type in question. If a field is `final`, on the other hand, there is no default value and it is a compiler error not to provide one at construction time.

Answer (score 0):

**-** `w3` if its a field (ie. `Instance variable`)

- By Default it will be initialized to `null` , as the **default Value of the Object Reference Variable is null.**

**-** Now if the Overloaded Constructor **doesn't initialize** it, its value will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the book nor have I ever read it. Therefore this is only a guess:

`w3` is a member variable of class

```
class A {
  public int w3; // w3 has no default initialization

  public B() {
    w3 = 1; // w3 is initialized here
  }

  public B(boolean x) {
    // w3 is not initialized here
  }  
}
```

You can do something like this:

```
A firstObject = new A();
System.out.println("firstObject.w3 is " + firstObject.w3);
A secondObject = new A(false);
System.out.println("secondObject.w3 is " + secondObject.w3);
```

Your output will be

```
firstObject.w3 is 1
secondObject.w3 is 0
```

Explanation: `firstObject` was created with the first constructor, which sets `w3` to `1`. `secondObject` was created with the overloaded constructor that needs a `boolean` parameter. This constructor does not set w3, nor is there a default initialization for `w3`. Therefore, it is never set. In Java, you get the following values for variables with no default initialization:

- `int/short/byte`: `0`
- `long`: `0L`
- `double`: `0.0d`
- `float`: `0.0f`
- `char`: `\u0000`
- `boolean`: `false`
- `Object` (and all derived classes): `null`
- `final` fields: they don't have a default value and throw a compiler error if there is no default initialization